Can I edit text color by letters in VS?
I work with .csv database and I need to color all words with specific color that start with letter "G" but i cant find tutorial or something that would help me.
I try settings.json with "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" but it only colors my columns. Then I try work with TODOs (TODO+) extension, but also nothing.
I need all word "GPCM_Norm" to be red
Thats my settings.json 

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I can't guess what you are trying to achieve but take a look at this highlight extension for VS Code.

@cachique No extensions help me with my problem...

It can only be a matter of the right regex in TODO+ but I don't think TODO+ is appropriate for the task.
As I suggested in my comment try highlight extension from the same author of TODO+. This is a more generic extension suitable for what yo try to achieve.
Add this to highlight.regexes section. It´s supposed to grab all words starting with G in data.csv file and color them red
        "(\\bG[\\w]+)": {
            "filterFileRegex": "data.csv",
            "decorations": [
                {
                    "color": "#ff0000"
                }
            ]

Change the regex "(\\bG[\\w]+)" to suit your needs, also the color and the filename
